# MongoDB accessing array fields

Tags: typescript, mongodb, asynchronous, nestjs

As the title says I am trying to access an array field from a query. The query works fine and can both console log and returning it works fine but when I try to access it I get undefined. Here is how I access it:
Creation of a query

```
async getTrack(id, type: String) : Promise<Track[]> {
if(type=='id'){
    const query = this.trackModel.find(
    { id : id },
    {_id:0}
  ).limit(100);
return query;
}
if(type=='name'){
    const query = this.trackModel.find(
  { name : id },
  {_id:0}
).limit(100);
return query;
}
}



let json = await this.trackService.getTrack(id, type);
json[0].artist_name



console.log(json[0].artist_name)


console.log(json[0])
```

The second console logs works fine while the first one fails and prints undefined.I have tried adding await inside as well as outside of the console.log to no avail as well as to try and put into string and nothing worked.

Comment: What's the result for `console.log(json[0])`?

Comment: The result is a track with all its fields as well as the "artist_name" field which is an array .It is the first element of the query as find() method returns an array(or at least this is how I've understood it).